# Google Books API - Getting Book Ratings?

Tags: python, ajax, google-books

I cannot find a way to get a Book's **Ratings** through the **Books API** provided by Google.

All I figured out is how to obtain search listings, which do not include **ratings and description**.

---

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Google Book API, but [its documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_php.html#RetrievingAnnotations) claims you can only retrieve an annotation (incl. review) for a specific user.

Another proof is some [post by Google employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/booksearch-apis/thread?tid=440c08aafea47b37&hl=en) who claims it's not supported (yet).